# Generate series of audio tones using iPython.display.Audio

Tags: python, audio, ipython, pyaudio

I would like to generate consecutive audio tones in iPython.  I've seen `pyo` but I can only get it to work in the `terminal`...I'd prefer to test out compositions in `iPython` if possible.

I recently found `iPython.display.Audio` and thought it could be a useful way to generate tones for animations.

```
# Generate a sound

from IPython.display import Audio 
import numpy as np

def waveform(freq,sec=1,sample_rate=44100):
    t = np.linspace(0,sec,sample_rate*sec)
    return(np.sin(np.pi*freq*t))

scale =   [440, 493.88, 523.25, 587.33, 659.25, 698.46, 783.99, 880.00]
sample_rate = 44100

Audio(waveform(440,sec=2),rate=sample_rate,autoplay=True)
```

So this works, it makes a little soundbox GUI that plays my tone. . . but I can't generate multiple tones when I try:

```
for note in scale:
    Audio(waveform(note,sec=2),rate=sample_rate,autoplay=True)
```

I'd really like to get `iPython.display.Audio` to work but I'm open to using other modules if it plays the tones in realtime (instead of just writing to file).  I've heard of `pyaudio` and `pygame` but I'm not sure if the sounds can be generated on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[edit] I realize I misread your question. My original answer was about combining tones, which you may still find useful so I left it below. You need to append your audio vectors to make one long tone, like this:

```
sequence = np.array([])
for note in scale:
    sequence = np.append(sequence, waveform(note, sec))
Audio(sequence,rate=sample_rate,autoplay=True)
```

If you want multiple tones to be played at once, keep reading.

---

Audio waves follow the *superposition principle*, so the combination of multiple waves is a linear sum of all the parts. This is super cool because it means you can combine multiple sounds by literally summing them, since you already have them in a nice vector form.

```
sec = 2
chord = waveform(0, sec) # silence
for note in scale:
    chord += waveform(note, sec)
Audio(chord,rate=sample_rate,autoplay=True)
```

Here's a pretty nice [page on superposition of waves](http://www.acoustics.salford.ac.uk/feschools/waves/super.php) as it relates to audio.

Comment: thanks for the great explanation.  i'm a little confused on what's going on with the chord. it doesn't need a 0 freq to initialize, right?

Comment: I'm exploiting the fact that `waveform` returns a silent waveform if you pass freq=0. Since `0` is the identity element under addition, we can use it to seed the summation reduction of the notes.